# Is it possible in CVS: "Clients not allowed to commit if there is no log written"?

Tags: linux, version-control, cvs, rhel

I am new to CVS. We recently started our version controlling by CVS. We are using SmartCVS on our RHEL systems as our CVS client.

Is it possible that my team members won't be able to commit if they have not put anything in log Message box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use hooks for that, as described [here](http://www.pragmaticautomation.com/cgi-bin/pragauto.cgi/Monitor/LettingCVSPullTheTrigger.rdoc/style/print), in the

> Write A Pre-Commit Filter

section.

Just out of curiosity - why would you want to use CVS, if there is git, mercurial, or even SVN?

Comment: because it looks simplest for me, to configure. i think ill shift to "bazaar" instead of your above mentioned.. as we can get distributed version controlling.. wt u say??

Comment: git and mercurial are also distributed, but if what canonical says on it's "why choose bazaar" doc page is true, you should be fine using bazaar as well. I'd say try them all for a few days, then decide.

Comment: really thanx @cabecao for ur help ... and definately i will do as per your suggesion. Thnx